# Creating a Jar and adding multiple streams to it

Tags: java, io, java-io

I am reading data from the database and writing the same to a buffered writer to create a fixed width file. I am also reading the same data and converting the same into a BSON file which would later be loaded by Mongo DB.

After the above process completes I am able to create a jar file for both these files and transfer them over the wire.

But to save time I have been advised to compress the data on the fly and create a jar file some thing like this

```
JarOutputStream jarOutPutStream = new JarOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(new File(file.getName() + ".jar")));

Writer bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(jarOutPutStream, "UTF-8"));
```

When I do the above and add the below code I am able to create a jar file on the fly.

```
JarEntry ze = new JarEntry("temp.log");
jarOutPutStream.putNextEntry(ze);
```

This jar has an entry temp.log but I would like to know how do I associate the other `FileOutputStream` with the above jar.

My output should be a jar file containing two entries: one for the fixed width file, and another for the BSON file.

Comment: My output should have jar file that has 2 files first fixed width file and second BSON file

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding via comment.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, if you want buffered I/O here then I strongly recommend putting the buffer *underneath* the Jar stream instead of on top:

```
JarOutputStream jarOutPutStream = new JarOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(new File(file.getName() + ".jar"))));
```

It requires great care to avoid corrupting your data if you manipulate both a wrapped stream and a wrapper stream, as it seems you propose to do by wrapping the Jar stream.

Secondly, the `file.getName() + ".jar"` is a bit fishy in light of your question.  There's nothing wrong with it as long as it produces a string that constitutes a valid filename, but don't think that the Jar file's name has any inherent association with its contents.

Thirdly, I'm uncertain whether you recognize that although your sample code demonstrates how to create a Jar file with a single entry, *it does not demonstrate actually adding any data for that entry*.  You are expected to do that by writing the data for the entry to the `JarOutputStream` after invoking `putNextEntry()`.

Fourth, and directly responding to your question, after writing the data for the first entry, you add an entry for the second file by creating an appropriate `ZipEntry` and invoking `putNextEntry()` on your stream again, with that entry.  Then you write the data for *that* entry.

Fifth, if you do not need to retain the two uncompressed files on the server, then you do not need to create them as files in the first place.  Instead, you can write each one's data directly to your `JarOutputStream` (serially), instead of writing to a separate file or to memory and then copying the data.

Sixth, if you do not need to retain the Jar file on the server, then you may be able to write it directly to the response stream, instead of to an intermediate file.  Whether or how you can do this depends on how you are delivering the response.

Seventh, is there any particular reason to use Jar instead of Zip?  They're the same thing except that valid Jar files contain a manifest, which you don't seem to need here.  All the things described above can be done the same way with a `ZipOutputStream` as with a `JarOutputStream` (which, in fact, is a subclass of `ZipOutputStream`).

Answer (score 0):

JAR files are in fact ZIP files. ZIP files do not allow non-consecutive storage of individual files within them. That is, File 1 appears in its entirety (compressed) in front of (or after, depends on the index) File 2.

I believe this makes it impossible to *stream* two or more streams into one single ZIP stream. It looks like you can stream one file into the ZIP OK, but need to cache the other one and add that to the ZIP later.

Are you forced to use the ZIP format? You want to look at container formats that support *interleaved* data. There, one chunk of File 1 can alternate with another chunk of File 2, so that you can emit chunks from either File iteratively.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have now created 2 jaroutput streams and have compressed them into a single jar and transferred them over the wire.

JarOutputStream jarOutPutStream = new JarOutputStream(
    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outputDatFile + ".jar"))));

  jarOutPutStream.setMethod(JarOutputStream.DEFLATED);

  JarEntry ze = new JarEntry(fileName);
  jarOutPutStream.putNextEntry(ze);

return jarOutPutStream;

After the jar i